# Write test class for Org wide email in apex

Tags: apex

I have the below code in Apex Utility Class

```java
public static OrgWideEmailAddress getOrgWideEmail()
{
    OrgWideEmailAddress orgWideEmail = [
           SELECT Id, DisplayName, Address
           FROM OrgWideEmailAddress
           WHERE DisplayName = :GlobalConstant.ORG_WIDE_ADDRESS 
           LIMIT 1
       ];
       return orgWideEmail;
}
```

Now i want this code to get covered from the test class:

I wrote the below code in test class but it is not getting covered:

```java
@isTest class ApexUtilityTest {
    @isTest static void test() {
        OrgWideEmailAddress[] addresses = [SELECT Id,DisplayName, Address FROM OrgWideEmailAddress LIMIT 1];
        System.assertEquals(1, addresses.size());
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Why don't you just call the getOrgWideEmail() method from the test class.

Comment: Yes. It worked for me. Thank you